# Social login with OAuth Provider for phpBB

Tags: php, web-services, oauth, phpbb

Okay, so in phpBB, OAuth service has already implemented as other authentication method for phpBB (in ACP > General > Authentication > Oauth), but phpbb only provides bitly, facebook, and google authentication by default ...

here's the picture :

[phpBB_OAuth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdSmP.png)

so how can I add other service beside those three ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you have knowledge of or Oauth works and the PHP workflow. 
I wanted to extend the providers as well and a while ago I found an extension for phpBB called "BBoauth" by SiteSplat. Here's a screenshot of what I have enabled on my phpBB forum:

[image: BBoauth - phpBB extension for extending oauth providers]

You can get a hold of a copy after you get the premium themes here: 
[phpBB theme](https://themeforest.net/user/themesplat/portfolio?ref=ThemeSplat)

It works great and the developer is top notch.